# Show only one border on input selector?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a input box that has only one border (i.e. border-left), but every time I put border-left to the selector, the top, right, bottom border show up (with that beveled and embossed look). Here's what I have right now.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="fullname" class="detail" name="fullname" value="" />
```

**CSS**

```
.detail {
    border-left: 1px #fff solid;
    background: transparent;
    width: 490px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XRFB3/

Comment: `border: 0;` before `border-left`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your default border first:

```css
.detail {
    border:0;
    border-left: 1px #fff solid;
    background: transparent;
    width: 490px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/XRFB3/1/)

Comment: Oh... I thought if I was to put that it'd cancel out the left one too. Thanks!

Comment: No the styles are applied one after the other (hence **cascading** style sheets)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset borders first `like border: none;`. That is because browsers apply default user agent styles if the custom is not defined.

```
.detail {
        border: none;
        border-left: 1px #fff solid;
        background: transparent;
        width: 490px;
        height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
border: none;
border-left: 1px Solid #fff;
```

instead of

```
border-left: 1px #fff solid;
```